# Are pages only secondary memory like hard drives, or are they used for RAM too?

Tags: operating-system

I'm confused by this.

Are pages only memory units that exist in secondary memory or do they also exist in RAM too?

Comment: A "page" is just a unit of storage (typically 4096 bytes on many systems). RAM is divided into pages. Memory pages might also be stored on secondary storage, to be loaded back into RAM at a later point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paging is a memory management scheme by which a computer stores and retrieves data from secondary storage for use in main memory. Pages are used in RAM too, as a solution of external fragmentation.

External fragmentation is a situation when total free space is enough to hold another process but space available is not contiguous. Compaction is one of the solution but for processes which are run-time loaded only. So, Paging is the true solution for external fragmentation where we implement page table which gives illusion that process has been given contiguous memory. Every address from CPU is broken down to page number and offset.

Answer (score 2):

A memory page is the smallest unit of memory used by a virtual memory manager. A page can be backed by physical RAM, or by swap space or a page file on a hard drive. Pages backed by RAM have much faster IO, but as RAM gets full the OS may have to swap out pages to the hard drive.

Answer (score 2):

Pages do not exist [physically] at all. A page is simply a redirection mechanism.

The operating system sets up of linear, logical address space for each process. The logical address space is organized into **pages** that in turn may map to:

1. A physical **page frame** of memory
2. No where
3. Somewhere on disk and managed by the operating system.